# Duplicated ActionBar on Fragment

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I made one `Activity` with a `NavigationView`. When I select one item of `NavigationView` it loads one `Fragment`.

This is the `Activity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

private DrawerLayout drawer;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_apresenta_atividades);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
}
...

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass;
    ...
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layout, fragment).commit();
    item.setChecked(true);
    setTitle(item.getTitle());
    drawer.closeDrawers();
    return true;
}
}
```

This is the xml for MainActivity and multiple Fragments:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ddffff"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    //Layout for FirstFragment
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        ...

    </RelativeLayout>

    //Layout for SecondFragment
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        ...

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#ddffff"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

When it starts one Fragment there are two ActionBars:
[image]

I don't understand how can I reorganize my .xml to just show ActionBar on top.
Thanks.

Edit: app_bar_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout   
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:id="@+id/co_layout" >

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

 </resources>
```

Comment: I see you are using a `Navigation Drawer Activity`. For this, you need to use a `NoActionBar` style. Can you check the manifest and see what style your `activity` is using?

Comment: I am already using that style for MainActivity.

Comment: Hmm... what is the layout in `@layout/app_bar_main`?

Comment: I paste it on my Question.

Comment: In that case, I don't think you need the `<include>` tag in there since you are including the fragments directly inside the main activity layout (I don't think this is recommended, though). Try removing the `<include>` tag and see what happens?

Comment: If I do that both disappear.

Comment: "This is the xml for MainActivity and multiple Fragments:" - If you're still using the `Activity`'s layout as the `Fragment`s' layouts, that's your problem. As I mentioned before, your `Fragment`s should be using separate, different layouts. Don't reuse the `Activity`'s in the `Fragment`s' `onCreateView()` methods.

Comment: @MikeM. I done what you propose and it is working now. Thanks. :)

Comment: @MikeM. Then put your answers. Then I accept them as right.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like that , don't request second `AppBarLayout` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".activity.HomeActivity">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/home_header_layout"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"

        app:menu="@menu/homepage_leftdrawer">


    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Consider `"Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"` attribute in your `styles.xml`, if you want to add `Toolbar` manually.

My `styles.xml` :

```
<style name="AppTheme3" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme3.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme3.AppBarTransparent" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

<style name="AppTheme3.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

And `styles-v21.xml` :

```
<style name="AppTheme3" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorFocusedHighlight">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/ColorControlHighlight</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>


<style name="AppTheme3.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme3.AppBarTransparent" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" >
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme3.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">

    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: If I do that both disappear.

Comment: @tomss can you update your styles.xml please, i will update my full xml

Comment: I past styles.xml on my question.

Comment: @tomss edited my answer for you

Comment: I used your CoordinatorLayout instead of my Layout xml and it does n't solved the problem.

Comment: did you changed your styles .